# Filter and Merge Dataset in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I am working on VS 2010 - Vb.Net, Having a syntax clarification on Filter & Merge DataSet

My dataset - ds has 23 tables. In which, i need to filter one Table with certain criteria.

```
tempDs.Merge(ds.Tables("p_tree_categories").Select( "GROUP_CODE <> 'PA.43.948'"))
```

On writing Merge Syntax,

I am able to see only selected table : p_tree_categories in the tempDs. We need the remaining 22 tables along with the filtered record of p_tree_categories.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you *only* want the filtered rows of table `p_tree_categories`. This being the case, I would:

1. Generate a copy of the `p_tree_categories` which only contains the rows you are interested in.
2. Remove the existing `p_tree_categories` from `tempDs`.
3. Merge the copy into `tempDs` as `p_tree_categories`.

These steps could be implemented something like this:

```
Dim originalTable As DataTable = tempDs.Tables("p_tree_categories")

Dim filterView As DataView = New DataView(originalTable)
filterView.RowFilter = "GROUP_CODE <> 'PA.43.948'"

Dim filteredTable As DataTable = filterView.ToTable
filteredTable.TableName = "p_tree_categories"

' Remove old, add the new.
tempDs.Tables.Remove(originalTable)
tempDs.Tables.Add(filteredTable)
```

Comment: Thank you , This is a great help !! My syntax works based on your suggestion. Thank you !!